# React TextArea value not automatically updating as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I was playing around in React and tried to make an app where you can display and modify any property in the component state, from the component itself. Basically, you enter a key (eg `"foo"`), and then the app will load the current value at that key (eg `this.state["foo"]`) into a textarea, where you can modify the value.

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-bird-6z6cx
And here is the code used in the sandbox:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputVal: ""
  };
  onKeyInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ key: e.target.value });
  }
  onValInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [this.state.key]: e.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          key: <input onChange={this.onKeyInputChange.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          value:
          <textarea
            onChange={this.onValInputChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state[this.state.key]}
          />
        </div>
        <h2>key: {this.state.key}</h2>
        <h2>value: {this.state[this.state.key]}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Notice how the `<textarea>`'s value and the `<h2>`'s value are both set to `this.state[this.state.key]`, so they should always show the same value. However, if you change the text value at say, key `"foo"`, and then change to key `"fooo"`, the h2's value will change but not the textarea. To put it more clearly:

1. type "foo" into the `key` input field
2. type "hello world" into the textarea
3. type "fooo" into the `key` input field
4. notice how the `<h2>`'s value is now blank, but the textarea still shows "hello world"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To resolve this issue, make sure that you're passing a "non-undefined" value to the textareas `value` prop [which will cause the textarea element to update](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-input-null-value) as expected.

A simple solution would be to pass an empty string for `value` in the undefined case which can be done like this `this.state[this.state.key] || ""`:

```
<textarea onChange={this.onValInputChange.bind(this)} 
          value={this.state[this.state.key] || ""} />
```

Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-rubin-gn47o)

Answer (score 2):

If `this.state[this.state.key]` is `undefined` the [controlled input (textarea) becomes editable](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-input-null-value).

This would mean that the value from the previous render will be retained.

You can play around with these conditions to prove:

```
// editable - value is retained
value={this.state.key === "foo" ? this.state[this.state.key] : null} 

// non-editable
value={this.state.key === "foo" ? this.state[this.state.key] : ""}
```

So to fix this, assign an empty string when `this.state[this.state.key]` is `undefined`.

```
<textarea
  onChange={this.onValInputChange.bind(this)}
  value={this.state[this.state.key] || ""} // if undefined, an empty string will be supplied
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do console this.state[this.state.key] you can see the **undefined** is being returned and if undefined is returned react does not know that what happened with your input and hence it does not update the **textArea** value.It is recommended to always pass an empty string instead of an undefined value.

similar issue discussion on github -> https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6222#issuecomment-194061477

Try to use arrow function , you do not need to bind the functions.

Working Example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-wildflower-1hqxi)

Comment: thanks for linking the github issue, I was looking for that